# it response yes in both condition if any instance active or not

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

i have trying to check if any t4g.micro spot is active if give response yes if there is no spot active

```
import boto3
import json
REGION = 'us-east-1'
def lambda_to_ec2(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
    spot_response = client.describe_spot_instance_requests(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'state',
                'Values': [
                    'active',
             ],
                'Name': 'launch.instance-type',
                'Values': [
                    't4g.micro',
                ],
            },
        ],
    )
    
    if spot_response:    
        print ("yes")
    else:
        print ("nooooo")
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: if there is no t4g.micro instance active it should print no

Answer (score 0):

Your `filter` is incorrect and also you missed to check `SpotInstanceRequests` in code. Below code should work:

```
import boto3

REGION = 'us-east-1'


def lambda_to_ec2(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=REGION)
    spot_response = client.describe_spot_instance_requests(
        Filters=[
            {
                'Name': 'state',
                'Values': ['active']
            },
            {
                'Name': 'launch.instance-type',
                'Values': [
                    't2.micro',
                ]
            }
        ],
    )
    if spot_response['SpotInstanceRequests']:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("nooooo")
```

Check out the [describe_spot_instance_requests](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_spot_instance_requests) API again.